# invalid initializer error for argv[0] and argv[1]?

Tags: c

Whenever I compile my c program, I get this error for both of my argv[]'s.
error: invalid initializer
char baseDir[] = argv[0];
error: invalid initializer
char pattern[] = argv[1];

This is a snippet of the main method in my program.

```
void walkDir(char *baseddir, char *pattern);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  char baseDir[] = argv[0];
  char pattern[] = argv[1];
  walkDir(baseDir, pattern);
  if(count==0){
     printf("No match found \n");
  }
printf("\n Done \n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char baseDir[] = argv[0];` should be `char* baseDir = argv[0];` (and the same for `pattern`)

Comment: Also, your indexes are off by one. `argv[0]` and `argv[1]` should be `argv[1]` and `argv[2]`. And you really should check `argc` before accessing `argv`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo When I do that I still get the same errors and a new warning. The warning is "warning: passing argument 1 of 'walkDIr' from incompatible pointer" and "warning: passing argument 2 of 'walkDIr' from incompatible pointer"

Comment: @YashPuranik That doesn't make sense since the pointer types match exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`argv[0]` and `argv[1]` are `char*`. They point at strings of unknown length. `argv[0]` usually holds a pointer to the name of the program itself while `argv[1]` holds a pointer to the first argument supplied to the program.

To initialize a `char[]` you need something like this:

```c
char baseDir[] = "a string literal";
```

In your case, it's not a string literal so you can't initialize a `char[]` with it, so you probably should just copy the pointers:

```c
const char *baseDir = argv[1]; // a pointer to the first argument
const char *pattern = argv[2]; // a pointer to the second argument
```

I added `const` since you shouldn't change the strings they are pointing at. I suppose you are not planning to change the strings in your `walkDir` function either, so then change it accordingly:

```
void walkDir(const char *baseddir, const char *pattern)
```

Comment: Thank you. I changed to what you suggested by I still get the same errors and a new warning: "warning: passing argument 1 of 'walkDIr' from incompatible pointer" and "warning: passing argument 2 of 'walkDIr' from incompatible pointer".

Comment: @YashPuranik I still don't know how `walkDir` is declared so I can't suggest a solution for that. If you added the definition of `walkDir` (or at least its declaration) to the question, I could possibly suggest how to deal with it.

Comment: walkDir is declared like this: void walkDir(char *baseddir, char *pattern){

Comment: @YashPuranik I included what you need to do in the answer. Do you still have a problem getting it to work?

Comment: No it do not! I fixed it using your help. Thank you very much.

Comment: @YashPuranik Ah, great to hear. You're welcome!